# How to write the texture() function from ShaderToy to Metal shading language?

Tags: swift, graphics, metal, metalkit

I am working on a custom Metal shader, and I am trying to replicate this particular effect from shader toy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3sfcR2

But I can't seem to understand how to convert their `texture()` function to the Metal shader format. Any ideas?
Here's what I have so far in Metal:

```c
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void chromaticAberration(texture2d<float, access::read> inTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                        texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(1) ]],
                        device const float *time [[ buffer(0) ]],
                        uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    float ChromaticAberration = 0.0 / 10.0 + 8.0;
    
    // get the width and height of the screen texture
    uint width = outTexture.get_width();
    uint height = outTexture.get_height();
    
    // set its resolution
    float2 iResolution = float2(width, height);
    
    float4 orig = inTexture.read(gid);
    float2 uv = orig.xy / iResolution.xy;
    
    float2 texel = 1.0 / iResolution.xy;
    
    float2 coords = (uv - 0.5) * 2.0;
    float coordDot = dot (coords, coords);
    
    float2 precompute = ChromaticAberration * coordDot * coords;
    float2 uvR = uv - texel.xy * precompute;
    float2 uvB = uv + texel.xy * precompute;
    
    // How to convert these texture() functions?
    float r = texture(iChannel0, uvR).r;
    float g = texture(iChannel0, uv).g;
    float b = texture(iChannel0, uvB).b;
    float a = 1.;
    
    const float4 colorAtPixel = float4(r,g,b,1.0);
    outTexture.write(colorAtPixel, gid);
    
}
```

**EDIT:**
Following the answer of @JustSomeGuy I was able to successfully replicate this shader in Metal. Here is the final version:

```c
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void chromaticAberration(texture2d<float, access::read> inTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                        texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(1) ]],
                        texture2d<float, access::sample> sampleTexture [[ texture(2) ]],
                        device const float *time [[ buffer(0) ]],
                        uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    
    float ChromaticAberration = 0.0 / 10.0 + 8.0;
    
    // get the width and height of the screen texture
    uint width = inTexture.get_width();
    uint height = inTexture.get_height();
    
    // set its resolution
    float2 iResolution = float2(width, height);
    
    float2 uv = float2(gid) / iResolution.xy;
    
    float2 texel = 1.0 / iResolution.xy;
    
    float2 coords = (uv - 0.5) * 2.0;
    float coordDot = dot (coords, coords);
    
    float2 precompute = ChromaticAberration * coordDot * coords;
    float2 uvR = uv - texel.xy * precompute;
    float2 uvB = uv + texel.xy * precompute;

    constexpr sampler s(address::clamp_to_edge, filter::linear);
    float r = sampleTexture.sample(s, uvR).r;
    float g = sampleTexture.sample(s, uv).g;
    float b = sampleTexture.sample(s, uvB).b;
    
    const float4 colorAtPixel = float4(r,g,b,1.0);
    outTexture.write(colorAtPixel, gid);
}
```

Kudos to @JustSomeGuy! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think I'm pretty good, but not this good. So take that into account. High level? Have you worked with Metal before? Have you done tis type of replication from anything - simple or not? Is the issue related to the Shader Toy texture? Or converting it to a Metal texture? What do you have working - anything? (That last is honestly meant respectfully.) Converting from `CoreImage` kernel code to Metal is tough enough for me - if it involves accessing pixels beyond the one being processed. So I guess my real question is this: can you get **any** shader working? I might help analyze the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think ShaderToy uses glsl or some of it's variants, so `texture` function is basically a `sample` call in Metal. Let's look at an example. I'm using [this doc](http://docs.gl/sl4/texture).  We'll use the 2D version since that's what you probably want.

```
gvec4 texture(  gsampler2D sampler,
                vec2 P,
                [float bias]);
```

So in this case `iChannel0` is your `sampler` and `uvR`, `uv`, `uvB` are texture coordinates (`P`). They should be `float2`.

So this is a global function that samples color for us from a sampler. In Metal, we have separate textures and samplers and you'll need both to sample. Also, in Metal `sample` is not a global function, but a member function of a `texture2d`. Let's look at [Metal Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), Section 6.10.3 "2D Texture". There we'll find a method:

```
Tv sample(sampler s, float2 coord, int2 offset = int2(0)) const
```

where `Tv` is the template parameter you have in your `texture2d` instantiation (probably `half` or `float`). It also takes a sampler and texcoords, so this code from your sample:

```
float r = texture(iChannel0, uvR).r;
float g = texture(iChannel0, uv).g;
float b = texture(iChannel0, uvB).b;
```

will turn into something like this:

```
constexpr sampler mySampler { filter::linear };
float r = iChannel0.sample(mySampler, uvR).r;
float g = iChannel0.sample(mySampler, uv).g;
float b = iChannel0.sample(mySampler, uvB).b;
```

And you will also need to pass `texture2d<float> iChannel [[texture(N)]]` (where `N` is the index you chose) to your shader the same way shadertoy does it (it's just a global var there, but in Metal you'd need to actually pass it as an argument).